# Android, Tomcat and Postman: Capture HTTP Requests

Tags: android, http, tomcat, request, postman

I want to capture the HTTP requests from my virtual device. I'm using Tomcat server, Android Studio and Postman. On this [page](https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/capturing-request-data/capturing-http-requests/) Postman team explains how to do it for a real IOS device. Here is the schema:

[image]

I though it would works same on Android virtual device so I went to *settings* on my android virtual device and I configured a proxy:

[image]

Also I tried to configur the proxy from *Android Studio settings*:

[image]

When I go to *Google Chrome App* and search, for example, Wikipedia it works fine. Always asking for permissions because the proxy is not savety but Postman is getting all the HTTP Request.

However when I try to connect to my App the connection doesn't work. The HTTP Request never reach the Postman or the Tomcat.

[image]

Someone know what could be the problem? I don't know much about architecture neither how to configure the connection. So I would be thakful if you detailed the solution.

I trying to find some guide for it. But it is been dificult.

Thank you so much.